# How can I send a C++ map<> to Python using Boost Python object?

Tags: python, c++, boost-python, stdmap

I want to pass `map<string, string>` from my C++ code to my Python code while I'm using `boost::python::object`. I want to use it as input parameters.

I define a dictionary in Python like this:

```
script_parameters = {}
```

And I pass my `map<string, string>` in C++ like this:

```
typedef map<string, string> CommandParametersMap;

if ( !command_parameters.empty() )
{
    CommandParametersMap::iterator begin = command_parameters.begin();
    CommandParametersMap::iterator end = command_parameters.end();
    boost::python::dict command_parameters_dict;
    for (CommandParametersMap::iterator it = begin; it != end; it++)
    {
        command_parameters_dict[it->first] = it->second;
    }
    m_script_global["script_parameters"] = command_parameters_dict; 
}
```

And then I run my Python file:

```
object o_result = exec(m_filescript->c_str(), m_script_global, m_script_global);
```

But here is the problem: `script_parameters` in my Python code is empty. What am I doing wrong in here?

I have to mention that all other parts of my code, such as executing scripts, work just fine. All I want to know is how I can pass data from C++ to Python with `boost::python::object`.

I tried another way but I still have the same problem:

I made `script_mode` in my Python code like this:

```
script_mode = ""
```

Then I tried to pass the string variable in C++ to Python like this:

```
m_script_global["script_mode"] = "Get_Script_Version";

object o_result = exec(m_filescript->c_str(), m_script_global, m_script_global);
```

When I try to get it back, it has the value I assigned to it in Python, which is `""`.

```
string mode = extract<std::string>(m_script_global["script_mode"]);
```

Comment: Are you sure !command_parameters.empty() is evaluating to true? Can you move the exec() to inside the same if-block to be sure? (But that's all I got, I know nothing about C++, just what jumped out as odd-looking.)

Comment: @AdamKG : To be sure its not empty i add pair in it before the block i mentioned. command_parameters.insert(std::make_pair("Script_Mode", "Get_Script_Version"));

Comment: I don't understand why you said you do: `script_mode = ""` in your script. If you do that, it will shadow the global you're feeding your Python script and will not work. Other than that, the C++ part seems okay to me.

Comment: Thank you so much netcoder, I thought if i wanna pass data to specific variable in python i must create the variable in python first then pass it,But i see now i don't have to, I removed it and now its working just fine, Thanks again man